# Cleaner approach to find and replace in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I'm currently attempting to read a file, pass the contents and multiple arrays to the function; see if any of it matches using regex and then replace & finally update.

The code I've put together which looks ugly and clumpy is this:

```
find_and_replace: function(file, ...items) {
    let str = _.clone(file);
    let valid = {};
    let do_escape = true;
    let hit;
    if (items != null ? items.length : void 0) {
        for (let i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++) {
            let obj = items[i];
            try {
                for (k in obj) {
                    let v = obj[k];
                    if (valid[k] == null) {
                        valid[k] = v;
                    }
                }
            } catch (error) { }
        }
        try {
            str = str.replace('/{{([\s\S]+?)}}/g', function(a, b) {
                if (hit = valid[b]) {
                    if (do_escape) {
                        return escape(hit);
                    } else {
                        return hit;
                    }
                }
                return '';
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
    return str;
},
```

The use of the function is as follows:

```
for (let _i = 0, _len = files.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    let x = files[_i];
    if(x.includes('node_modules')) {
        continue;
    }
    builder.find_and_replace(builder.read_file(x), main_config, second_config);
    break;
}
```

The functionality of this "system" is to find any `{{tag}}` placeholders from within the file & replace with the correct key from inside the `...items` combined array

I'd greatly appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction to lower the amount of code required.

Comment: can you perhaps include the use for the function and expected output in your question?

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski I've gone ahead and included the intended use of this function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some simplification may include using `Object.entries` or `Array.reduce` methods

```
function find_and_replace(file, ...items) {
  let str = _.clone(file);
  let do_escape = true;
  let hit;

  if (items != null ? items.length : void 0) {
    const valid = items.reduce((valid, obj) => {
      Object.entries(obj)
        .map([k, v] => {
          valid[key] = v;
        });
      return valid;
    }, {});

    try {
      str = str.replace('/{{([\s\S]+?)}}/g', (a, b) => hit === valid[b] ? (do_escape ? escape(hit) : hit) : '');
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
  return str;
},
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use function rest parameters (`...items`), you always get an array under `items` so `if (items != null ? items.length : void 0)` is redundant.

`items.reduce((all, obj) => ({...all, ...obj}), {})` creates single object from `...items`

`` (string, [key, value]) => string.replace(new RegExp(`{{${key}}}`, "gi"), value) `` will find all occurrences of keys from object and replace them with values

```js
const tr = (string, ...items) => "" + Object.entries(items.reduce((all, obj) => ({...all, ...obj}), {})).reduce((string, [key, value]) => string.replace(new RegExp(`{{${key}}}`, "gi"), value), string);

console.log(tr("{{h}} {{w}}!", {h:"Hello"}, {w:"world"}));
```